# MySQL is not starting, Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.user' in tablespace 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, mysqlupgrade

I was not sure about upgrade but not I'm not able to start MySQL server:

Here is log file, Is there any way rollback or fix this issue?

```
2023-11-02T10:19:05.540585Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE user MODIFY ssl_type enum('','ANY','X509', 'SPECIFIED') NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 3664, error message = 'Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.user' in tablespace 'mysql'.'.
2023-11-02T10:19:05.547705Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2023-11-02T10:19:05.548711Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-11-02T10:19:06.568213Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2023-11-02T10:19:07.266239Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 13750
2023-11-02T10:19:07.273706Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-02T10:19:07.826137Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Oh finally it's started now.

Just these 3 commands:

```bash
sudo systemctl stop mysql
/usr/sbin/mysqld --upgrade=MINIMAL
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Hope it will help someone.